# Store and iterate function pointers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, function-pointers

I would like to store function pointers in an Array and then execute all of them in a foreach loop.

```
var array = new Array();

array['foo'] = function() { doFoo(); };
array['bar'] = function() { doBar(); };
```

How do I iterate and execute all functions in array?

Comment: JavaScript arrays are intended to be used with numeric indexes. Assigning to the same index twice overwrites the previous assignment.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Updated my question. The double iteration was not my question. Sorry for being a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you really want to use non-numeric property names, you don't need an array:

```
var obj = {};

obj["foo"] = function() { doFoo(); }
obj["bar"] = function() { doBar(); }
```

To iterate and call the functions:

```
for (var k in obj) {
  obj[k]();
}
```

To be pedantic, it's usually considered a good idea to make sure you're not running into unexpected properties inherited from the prototype:

```
for (var k in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(l))
    obj[k]();
}
```